# drupal mailchimp campaigns content sections missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, mailchimp

tl;dr: i need help to setup drupal mailchimp campaigns.

Hi.

I'm struggling to set up mailchimp campaigns for a drupal website. 
Following the mailchimp tutorial on drupalize.me (https://drupalize.me/videos/send-campaigns-drupal?p=2235)
I have succesfully linked mailchimp module with my mailchimp account with app API keys, subscribed drupal users to mailchimp list and sent test campaign from mailchimp to my drupal users. Works as designed so far.

I have a problem with sending mailchimp campaign from drupal. According to documentation and tutorials provided, i should be able to insert content into template sections from within drupal mailchimp campaign configuration page.
The thing is: there are no content sections to edit. I tried with both default mailhimp templates and themes, also made some templates on mailchimp app, exported them then imported as html. All templates appear in drupal mailchimp campaigns tab as available, but when i click any of them, the ajax content sections form is just empty. When there are no templates selected, the form allows me to insert some content or node into template, therefore i can tell that the ajax form component is working as designed.

Troubleshooting so far: I tried to make this work on 3 drupal 7 installations and a drupal 8 installation, across two vps instances, with no success.
On one instance i got an ajax error witn var dump for data sent back from mailchimp, and the sections object is simply empty.

I run out of ideas here, and would appreciate some input from successful mailchimp campaigns users.

Answer (score 2):

You need to code your own template at the Mailchimp site. The Mailchimp templates seem to miss the editable areas which are needed to insert content in Drupal.

You can export and re-import an existing template and add the editable section. There is a simple tutorial which explains this step.

https://drupalize.me/videos/create-custom-email-template?p=2235

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here found. So far i found out two things:

A few of the Mailchimp templates showing the content section, e. g. Order invoice, Refund confirmation or Cancellation information.

Do not use development environment with localhost. Your Drupal needs to be accessible via internet.